# Rename JSON tag when not all Struct values can be converted to interface{}

Tags: go

Say I have the following `struct` and I want to rename X and Y according to some string variables in my code.

```
type RenameStruct struct {
    X map[string]interface{}
    Y []map[string]interface{}
}
```

What is the best approach to have them Renamed when Encoding to JSON ? 
The ones I found here in StackOverflow seems to not be applicable to a `struct` where one field is an `interface{}` ant the other an `[]interface{}`.

Edit: I used Dave's answer to create a list of the "RenameStruct" this way: [play.golang.org/p/hKZQvhJV2iL](https://play.golang.org/p/hKZQvhJV2iL)

Comment: What do you mean? Struct field names are set at compile time and cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: I mean changing them when Encoding to JSON. I will edit the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a custom JSON marshaller, and then have some way of passing in the names you want.  The only easy way I can think of would be to do:

```
type RenameStruct struct {
    X map[string]interface{}
    Y []map[string]interface{}
    xName string
    yName string
}

func (r RenameStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    data[r.xName] = r.X
    data[r.yName] = r.Y
    return json.Marshal(data)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cpjgJ5tpcK3